# Changing checkbox array from single to multiple select

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to change the code below to allow for multiple checkboxes to be selected. It currently saves and updates only one selction. And to update the option again, I have to "uncheck" the previous selection then make another single selection for it to save.

```
    case 'tax_select': 
$terms = get_terms( $field['id'], 'get=all' ); 
$selected = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $field['id'] ); 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    printf( '<input type="checkbox" name="%s[]" value="%s" %s/><br />', $field['id'], $term->slug, !empty( $selected ) && !strcmp( $term->slug, $selected[0]->slug ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ); 
} 
$taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $field['id'] ); 
echo '<span class="description"><a href="' . get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $field['id'] . '">Manage ' . $taxonomy->label . '</a></span>'; 
break;
```

NEWLY ADDED: HOW I AM SAVING THE DATA:

```
    // Save the Data
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
global $custom_meta_fields;

// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
    return $post_id;
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
        return $post_id;
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
}

// loop through fields and save the data
foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
            if($field['type'] === 'tax_select') continue;
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
} // end foreach

    // save taxonomies
$post = get_post($post_id);
$category = $_POST['category'];
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category, 'category' );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');
```

Comment: i think there is some code missing. how do you save the data? the code above seems to just display the checkboxes.

Comment: Eyal, thank you for taking a look at this.  I added the code I'm using to save the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and days of frustration, I'm proudly answering my own question.

The original code was not displaying multiple checkboxes because I was using the conditional `!strcmp( $term->slug, $selected[0]->slug )` to render my "checked" options. Somehow it only returned 1 "checked" value at best.

The correct conditional simply gets the value of the selected option, and then verifies whether or not it exists in the `$meta` array in order to return a `checked="checked"` value.  Hence the code below:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  
echo '<label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$term->slug.'</label>';

       if (!empty ($selected) && in_array($term->slug, $meta))
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" value="'.$term->slug.'" checked="checked"/><br />';

else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" value="'.$term->slug.'"/><br />';
}
```